# if else condition in ggplot to cluster selective positive and negative returns with different color

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have data like this

```
> Dataframe 

 Time                   PercentReturn 
2014-07-30 09:02:00     -0.35545061  
2014-07-30 09:03:00     -0.20793116
2014-07-30 09:04:00      0.62250090 
2014-07-30 09:05:00     -0.34041326
2014-07-30 09:06:00      0.31085807
2014-07-30 09:07:00      0.00000000
```

what I want to do is to make a ggplot of the returns which are greater or less than 0.2 using a if else statement with two different colors (like red for greater than 0.2 and blue for lesser than 0.2)

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me where you got stuck, but if this is your sample data

```
dd<-structure(list(Time = structure(c(1406725320, 1406725380, 1406725440, 
1406725500, 1406725560, 1406725620), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), PercentReturn = c(-0.35545061, -0.20793116, 0.6225009, 
-0.34041326, 0.31085807, 0)), .Names = c("Time", "PercentReturn"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

then you can make such a plot with

```
ggplot(dd, aes(Time, PercentReturn, 
   color=cut(PercentReturn, breaks=c(-Inf, -.2, .2, Inf), 
   labels=c("less","neutral","greater")))) + 
geom_point() + 
scale_color_manual(values=c("greater"="red", less="blue", 
   neutral="black"), guide="none")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for the help , I made a mistake in posting the question as the condition should have been red for greater than 0.2 and blue for lesser than -0.2

Comment: Please be careful when positing a question. Carefully edit and verify so you don't create unnecessary work for others answering your question. I've updated my response accordingly.